# Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument

Tags: react-native, razorpay

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Joz0.jpg)
I am developing an ios app but i got dependency issues and

> Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument. error

---

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
const razorpayEvents = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.RazorpayEventEmitter);
```

> NativeModules.RazorpayEventEmitter is empty .

Comment: I ended up solving this by properly setting up an unrelated native module. (for expo through their large convoluted process)

Answer (score 35):

Go to ios folder then remove

1. Pods & Podfile.lock
2. run pod install
3. Rebuild project

And make sure you have followed the installation instruction correctly.
[Drawer Installation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#installation)

I hope it can solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I used drawer navigation in my react app and then faced same issue.
Go to ios directory and say pod install.
Rebuild your application.
This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have added below line in my `.zshrc` file:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and then i ran command

`source .zshrc`

to save the changes in .zshrc file.

then did `pod install` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm i (check if you have any failed dependency downloads and user either --force or --legacy-peer-deps)
2. cd ios && pod install
3. cmd + shift + k and re-run your app!