# Error: Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, navigation-drawer

I am trying to make a drawer menu on my app. I have followed this installation guide [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#installation).

I have this code

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';  


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

My app fails to render when I try to create the drawer object with the `createDrawerNavigator()` hook. I get the error

**Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument.**.

I have looked at some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083890/invariant-violation-new-nativeeventemitter-requires-a-non-null-argument) that say I should delete the pod and the pod.lock file and then install the pod again, but I still get the same issue even after doing this and reinstalling the pods.

Any insight on what could be wrong is appreciated!!